# unable to delete file from the app documents folder

Tags: ios, swift

Using Swift 3, I'm writing a video file to the documents folder.
here's the path of the file.

`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D031AB20-CB7E-4B14-9483-E7C3F4C0EC55/Documents/output11:10:04.mov`

now I want to delete the file again using the `filemanager`. I retrieve the path above from the `avassetwriter` and use the `outputurl` I defined earlier to remove the file using the filemanager.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

   do {
       try fileManager.removeItem(at: (self.assetWriter?.outputURL)!)
      } catch let err {
        print(err)
      }
```

but I get the error that there is no such file or directory.
using `self.assetWriter?.outputURL.path`gives me the same error.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“output11/10/04.mov” couldn’t
>   be removed."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D031AB20-CB7E-4B14-9483-E7C3F4C0EC55/Documents/output11:10:04.mov,
>   NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Remove ), NSUnderlyingError=0x174240150 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Comment: before deleting file , please check if file is exist at that path or not? As your error is showing that this file is not exists at location.

Comment: **output11:10:04.mov** is file name not t Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "  **output11/10/04.mov**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use colons in file names.

(For legacy reasons) the OS treats them as path separators and replaces them with slashes.

Comment: thanks this is part of the problem that got solved. But I'm still getting the error. Something is not right with the file path

Comment: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“output12-37-45.mov” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FECB3191-7684-4D3E-9F99-120F17D74046/Documents/output12-37-45.mov, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
), NSUnderlyingError=0x170243c30 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}`

Comment: error was the same, but due to another bug. solved it now.

Answer (score 3):

First Check weather the file exist at this path or not if exist then delete it :-

```
let file_manager = FileManager.init()
        if let url = self.assetWriter?.outputURL{
            if file_manager.fileExists(atPath: url.path){
                if file_manager.isDeletableFile(atPath: url.path){
                    do {
                        try file_manager.removeItem(at: url)
                    } catch let err {
                        print(err.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: the file is definitely there. I can see it when I go to the app folder in itunes. this code doesn't produce any errors, but it doesn't delete the file either.

Answer (score 3):

remove "file://" string from starting.

```
 let path = documentPathValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "")
```

complete code

```
 func clearAllFilesFromDirectory() {

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as NSURL
    let documentsPath = documentsUrl.path

    do {
        if let documentPathValue = documentsPath{

            let path = documentPathValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "")
            let fileNames = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "\(path)")
            print("all files in cache: \(fileNames)")

            for fileName in fileNames {

                let tempPath = String(format: "%@/%@", path, fileName)

                //Check for specific file which you don't want to delete. For me .sqlite files
                if !tempPath.contains(".sql") {
                    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: tempPath)
                } 
            }
        }

    } catch {
        print("Could not clear document directory \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: So frustrating that the function simply cant interpret file:// for us. It's like a browser throwing an error for excluding "http://" from the beginning of your URL.

Comment: I second this frustration. A long time ago, I know, but what is `format: "%@/%@"` for?

Comment: Oh god, don't use `String(format:)` to join path components together. That's what URL's APIs are for.