# What is the relevance of this String format specifier?

Tags: swift, string, format-specifiers

I'm trying to get an understanding of some code I came across recently.

In an answer to a question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51173170/1162328, the author made use of a String with a format specifier when looping over files in the documentDirectory. Can anyone shed some light on what `%@/%@` is actually doing?

```
for fileName in fileNames {
    let tempPath = String(format: "%@/%@", path, fileName)
    // Check for specific file which you don't want to delete. For me .sqlite files
    if !tempPath.contains(".sql") {
        try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: tempPath)
    } 
}
```

Reading the [Apple documentation archive for Formatting Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943-SW1) I came across this:

> In format strings, a ‘%’ character announces a placeholder for a value, with the characters that follow determining the kind of value expected and how to format it. For example, a format string of "%d houses" expects an integer value to be substituted for the format expression '%d'. NSString supports the format characters defined for the ANSI C functionprintf(), plus ‘@’ for any object.

What exactly then, is `%@/%@` doing?

Comment: `%@` in Swift is the same as interpolation. `let tempPath = "\(path)/\(fileName)"`

Comment: Don't use this answer. `String(format: "%@/%@", path, fileName)` is not how any moderately experience swift dev would write this. String concatination (`path + filename`) or interpolation (`"\(path)/\(filename))` are much more reasonable ways of joining strings. But more importantly, you shouldn't be using Strings to model paths/urls that's what URL is for, and it already has a wonderful `appendingPathComponent` API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%@` is something similar to `%d` or anything like that. This is the way of string interpolation in Swift.

To be exact `%@` is placeholder for object - used in Objective-C A LOT. Since `NSString *` was object (now it is only String), it was used to insert `NSString *` into another `NSString *`.

Also given code is just rewritten objective-c code which was something like

```
NSString *tempPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", path, filename];
```

which can be rewritten in swift:

```
let tempPath = path + "/" + fileName
```

Also, given path = "Test" and fileName = "great" will give output Test/great.

One more note: %@ is as good as dangerous. You can put UITableView as well as String in it. It will use description property for inserting into string.

Answer (score 4):

Each format specifier is replaced by one of the following arguments (usually in the same order, although that can be controlled with positional arguments). So in your case, the first `%@` is replaced by `path` and the second `%@` is replaced by `fileName`. Example:

```
let path = "/path/to/dir"
let fileName = "foo.txt"
let tempPath = String(format: "%@/%@", path, fileName)
print(tempPath) // /path/to/dir/foo.txt
```

The preferred way to build file names and paths is to use the corresponding `URL` methods instead of string manipulation. Example:

```
let pathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let tempURL = pathURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
if tempURL.pathExtension != "sql" {
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempURL)
}
```